# method wrong output

Tags: java, arrays, methods

When I enter the code I get an output like [I@190d11. How can I solve it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int N;
    N = 10; 
    System.out.println(getRandom(N));           
}

public static int[] getRandom(int N)
{
    int i, j, x, y;
    Random generator = new Random();
    int[] random = new int[N * 2];
    x = (2 * N) - 1;
    y = -N;
    for(i = y; i <= N; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N - 1; j++)
        random[j] = generator.nextInt(x - y - 1) + y;
    }
    return random;
}
```

I think it is related with static but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: the printout is correct as you are printing an `int[]` If you are looking for the actual values you need to loop the array for the values

Comment: @harold_finch what is the output you expect

Comment: Its printing array.SO it will like that only .

Comment: Replace the output line with System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getRandom(N)));

Comment: I want an array sized 19 with all array has a random number between -10 and 10.

Comment: Check my answer, and it has nothing to do with static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing array , whose default to String pringts objectName and hashCode.
If you want to print all the values in array use :-

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getRandom(N)));
```

Or iterate over the array and print each element separatly

Comment: that will work thanks

Comment: welcome, your question is actually duplicate but only reason i answered it, cause you were not able to figure out you were fetching array from method. So, it is possible to miss such detail. Could you except this answer by clickin a tick in side of answer.